# Sorting and Merging Using spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a string array in scala

```
Array[String] = Array(apple, banana, oranges, grapes, lichi, anar)
```

I have converted it into a format like this:

```
Array[(Int, String)] = Array((5,apple), (6,banana), (7,oranges), (6,grapes), (5,lichi), (4,anar))
```

and i want output like this:

```
Array[(Int, String)] = Array((4,anar), (5,applelichi), (6,bananagrapes), (7,oranges))
```

means after sorting i want to add together the words with same key.
i have done sorting. heres my code:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("apple","banana","oranges","grapes","lichi","anar"))
val b = a.map(x =>(x.length,x))
val c = b.sortBy(_._2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupByKey()` to do this and then merge the lists you get with `mkString`. Small example using what you have (a,b are the same):

```
val c = b.groupByKey().map{case (key, list) => (key, list.toList.sorted.mkString)}.sortBy(_._1)

c.collect() foreach println
```

Which will give you:

```
(4,anar)
(5,applelichi)
(6,bananagrapes)
(7,oranges)
```

Comment: it is giving (6,grapesbanana) but i want (6,bananagrapes)

Comment: @Rohit Added a sort when merging the fruits. Now you should get them in order.

Comment: thanks but if i have a rdd like ((a,b),c) and i want to group by key and add values of c if (a,b) is equal

Comment: `((Deeapak,male),4000), ((Deepak,male),2000), ((Deepika,female),2000), ((Deepak,female),2000), ((D
eepak,male),1000), ((Neeta,female),2000)` like this and merge if (a,b) are same. so that output will be like `(Deepak,female,2000)

(Deepak,male,3000)

(Deeapak,male,4000)

(Neeta,female,2000)

(Deepika,female,2000)`

Comment: @Rohit you should be able to use exactly the same method with (a,b) as key. If by add values you mean adding numbers together, then you can replace the `mkString` with `sum` (in this case you can also remove the toList and sorted).

Comment: @ Shaido I have this data `Array[((String, String), Int)] = Array(((Deeapak,male),4000), ((Deepak,male),2000), ((Deepika,female),2000), ((Deepak,female),2000), ((D
eepak,male),1000), ((Neeta,female),2000))
` it is in form of rdd and i want to apply `groupbKey()` operation on this data. i tried but i gives me this error `error: value groupbyKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Int)]
              pairRDD.groupbyKey()`

Comment: @Rohit It should definitely work as long as you have a key-value RDD. Are you sure your RDD is RDD[((String, String), Int)] and not RDD[(String, String, Int)]? The first case will work but not the second one. Also, make sure you write `groupByKey()` with capital B and K.